# ibm-application-bnd.xml overwritten

Tags: maven, websphere, jrebel

I work on an existing Maven project with Eclipse Luna and WebSphere 8.5.5.1.

The source of the ibm-application-bnd.xml is:
D:\projects\svn\application\ear\src\main\application\META-INF\ibm-application-bnd.xml

Once a day, at a random moment, the application folder itself is overwritten with the ear-file, so the \main folder contains a binary file named application and is actually the ear file because I openend the file because I saw it had the same size as the ear (8 MB).:
D:\projects\svn\application\ear\src\main\application

The happens at least once a day, and I have the impression that Eclipse, or JRebel of WebSphere creates this file.
The result is that I have to quit Eclipse, delete the file and update from SVN to get the application folder with the binding xml back.

Any thought how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way you could stop the folder from being deleted (and perhaps also find the culprit) is to open command prompt in that directory - it won't allow the folder to be removed in that case.

Comment: I will give that a try because there will be an error generated by the component that tries to write a file there.

Comment: It is definitely WebSphere 8.5 that overwrites the folder 'application' with the file 'application' ear. 
It happened once after clicking Clean on the Server menu, and later after redeployment of the ear and after restarting the server.